# Accessing IndexController problem?

Tags: module, xml, configuration

hi this is my xml file from app/etc/modules/Attila2_ModulTest.xml :

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Attila2_ModulTest>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Attila2_ModulTest>
    </modules>
</config>
```

this is the config.xml from app/code/local/Attila2/ModulTest/etc/config.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Attila2_ModulTest>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Attila2_ModulTest>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <modultest>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Attila2_ModulTest</module>
                    <frontName>ModulTest</frontName>
                </args>
            </modultest>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and this is the IndexController.php code from app/code/local/Attila2/ModulTest/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
class Attila2_ModulTest_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){
        echo "test";
    }
}
```

I cleared the caches.
When i access the http://attin.netlogiq.info/magento/index.php/modultest , I get the 404 errors instead of my string "test". why ?

Comment: please give the code of the  app/code/local/Attila2/ModulTest/config.xml need to check that file also if any errors presents

Comment: please check now the post

Comment: please check the spelling mistake of fronted

Comment: I get text "test" when I clicked your link?

Comment: if still not worked please check the spaces.for eg their should be no space from the strat of <?xml tag etc

Comment: now it works ! I changed the "<frontName>ModulTest</frontName>"into this "<frontName>modultest</frontName>" , but why i have to use lowercase ?

Comment: if you think my answer has helped you please upvote and please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <modultest>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Attila2_ModulTest</module>
                    <frontName>modultest</frontName>
                </args>
            </modultest>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
```

please check their is a spelling mistake of frontend

Comment: I changed into "frontend", but nothing happened, still 404

Comment: now i had changed frontname please check modultest

Comment: yeah it works, but why must i have to change it into lowercase letters?

Comment: the name whatever you specifie in the <frontName> tag will be used in the url.so you specified name in caps and using small letters in the url

Answer (score 0):

Please add `<frontend>` instead of `<fronted>`

It should be something like this

```
<frontend>
        <routers>
            <routeurfrontend>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Attila2_ModulTest</module>
                    <frontName>ModulTest</frontName>
                </args>
            </routeurfrontend>
        </routers>
</frontend>
```

Comment: I followed the example from this link : http://www.insync.co.in/creating-custom-module-magento/

Comment: Follow above given code and you will get it.. rest seems fine.. also recheck the link.. you made a typo.. it should be frontend not fronted... :)

Comment: I copy pasted your code and i get still the 404

Comment: have you added `<?xml version="1.0"?>` in config.xml?